# In Android Studio , is re-installation normal when you exit ?

Tags: android, android-studio, installation, exit

In Android Studio , is re-installation normal when you exit ?
When I close the Android and reopen it , I m surprised to see the re-installation . It 's faster than the first time but I m surprised because it shouldn't happen , should it ? 
I ve clicked right on the Android icon on my dashboard and chose open . and then it re install it . 
https://www.cjoint.com/c/HKyser3pjSw
Is it what I had to do ? 
thanks a lot for your help ! 
sam

Answer (score 0):

You should run .exe file of android studio, its name is `studio64`(windows platform) :
[image]

android it located in folder like:

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin
```

Comment: Do you write this line in the terminal ? C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin